# How can use a loop variable in function as a parameter of same function in php

Tags: php, function, variables

```
<?php

klmn("<input type='button'  value='$x'>");

function klmn($st){   
    echo "<table>";
    for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) 
    {
        echo "<td>".$st ." </td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

when ı run this code , ı cannot see buttons values from 1 to 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass your argument, the `$x` is the current var (outside the scope of your function), probably you got a notice for undefined variable.

You should do a `str_replace` of a placeholder

```
klmn("<input type='button'  value='\$x'>"); // note the backslash \$x

function klmn($st){   
    echo "<table>";
    for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) 
    {
        echo "<td>".str_replace('$x',$x,$st) ." </td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function klmn($st){   
    echo "<table>";
    for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) 
    {
        echo "<td>". str_replace('$x', $x, $st) ." </td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
klmn('<input type="button"  value="$x">');
```